# How to set QAction to have transparent background inside QToolBar

Tags: qt

After creating a QToolBar I'm adding QAction to it with icons, but when I set QToolBar StyleSheet QAction will have a white background instead of a transparent one like in the photo below

[image]

code:

```
QToolBar *toolBarFile = addToolBar("File");
toolBarFile->setMinimumWidth(70);
this->addToolBar(Qt::LeftToolBarArea, toolBarFile);
toolBarFile->setMovable(false);
toolBarFile->setStyleSheet("*{border: none;}"
                           "QToolBar{background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 0, stop: 0 #f2f2f2, stop: 0.8 #f2f2f2, stop: 1 #999999);}");

QAction* ActionUniversal = new QAction(QIcon(":/DownArrow.png"), "&Open", this);
toolBarFile->addAction(ActionUniversal);

ActionUniversal = new QAction(QIcon(":/DownArrow.png"), "&Open", this);
toolBarFile->addAction(ActionUniversal);

ActionUniversal = new QAction(QIcon(":/DownArrow.png"), "&Open", this);
toolBarFile->addAction(ActionUniversal);

ActionUniversal = new QAction(QIcon(":/DownArrow.png"), "&Open", this);
toolBarFile->addAction(ActionUniversal);
```

Another example that shows the transparency of the background of my image:

[image]

what has changed in my code:

```
toolBarFile->setStyleSheet("border: none;"
                               "background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 0, stop: 0 #f2f2f2, stop: 0.8 #f2f2f2, stop: 1 #999999);");
```

Comment: And are you sure that DownArrow.png has transparent background? I think this would be the problem of yours that it does not.

Comment: yes and i'll add something to show you another behavior

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. The stylesheet got obviously inherited from the parent widget. So you need to set the transparent background for the buttons. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
toolBarFile->setStyleSheet("QToolButton{border: none; background-color: transparent;} "
                           "QToolBar{background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 0, stop: 0 #f2f2f2, stop: 0.8 #f2f2f2, stop: 1 #999999);}");
```